# Case insensitive queries

Tags: google-bigquery

We're also switching to bigQuery, right now i am setting on my desk and exploring BigQuery
In my database. i have a table called `SearchAPI` contains `userId, userDisplayName, username`

and they have `

```
[{"username":"bushra","userDisplayname":"Bushra Ahmed Shaswar","userId":"fsds"},

{"username":"Amigo_123","userDisplayname":"Amigo Bachora","userId":"Amigo"}]
```

However when i query `B` capital it gives me the above result, but with a small `b` it returns nothing..

here's my query:

```
  var theQuery = '%' + req.query.name + '%';

  // The SQL query to run
  const sqlQuery = `
  SELECT
   username, userDisplayname,userId
  FROM
   WordsDatabase.SearchAPI
  WHERE
   userDisplayname Like '${theQuery}'`;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Option 1

```sql
var theQuery = '%' + req.query.name + '%';

// The SQL query to run
const sqlQuery = `
SELECT
 username, userDisplayname,userId
FROM
 WordsDatabase.SearchAPI
WHERE
 LOWER(userDisplayname) Like LOWER('${theQuery}')`;
```

Option 2

```sql
var theQuery = req.query.name;

// The SQL query to run
const sqlQuery = `
SELECT
 username, userDisplayname,userId
FROM
 WordsDatabase.SearchAPI
WHERE
 REGEXP_CONTAINS(userDisplayname, r'(?i)${theQuery}'`;
```